# How to find a file name by using extension for searching

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to get the specific file name by searching via extension.

This is my code:

```
for /r "C:\Directory" %%x in (*.msu) do echo "%%x"
```

What I get after run this code: **`C:\Directory\something.msu`**

What I want actually: **`something.msu`**

Please help if you have any ideas.

Comment: take a look at the output of `for /?`. note the "modifier" paragraph, then `... do echo "%%~nxx"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` variables have modifiers, so you can exactly define what part of a filename you want. For example `%%~n_` is for **N**ame, `%%~x_` is for E**x**tension and so on (see `for /?` for a full list of possible modifiers). You can combine them as `%%~nx_` for **N**ame plus E**x**tension.

It's recommended (although not obligatory) to use uppercase variable names to avoid confusion with the modifiers (or lower case variable names and upper case modifiers), so to achieve your goal, use:

```
for /r "C:\Directory" %%X in (*.msu) do echo "%%~nxX"
```

(recommended syntax) or:

```
for /r "C:\Directory" %%x in (*.msu) do echo "%%~NXx"
```

Also working fine but maybe confusing if you are not used to it:

```
for /r "C:\Directory" %%x in (*.msu) do echo "%%~nxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `/S` switch of the basic `dir` command: this goes into all subdirectories:

```
dir /S *.msu
```

=> this gives a whole bunch of explanation. If you want to filter (just having the filename):

```
dir /S *.msu | findstr ".msu"
```

=> `findstr` is the Windows equivalent of `grep`.

As mentioned by @aschipfl, this command is even better:

```
dir /S /N /A:-D *.msu | findstr /I /E "\.msu"
```

Most important:

- `/A:-D` means : don't show directory
- /I : case insensitive

Comment: @aschipfl ..which would give the full path - which is not wanted.

Comment: Yes, @Stephan is right, `/S` without `/B` gives pure names only; but then I'd improve the code like this: `dir /S /N /A:-D *.msu | findstr /I /E "\.msu"` (exclude directories by `/A:-D`; `.msu` must occur at the end if the file name by `/E`; Windows treats file names case-insensitively, so should the filter `/I`)